# TypeError: migrationCreator is not a function

Tags: javascript, contentful, contentful-management

I am trying to `createAsset` using the [content-management-api](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-management-api/#/reference/assets/assets-collection/create-an-asset/console/js).

The JavaScript script that I am using is

**./contentful/contentful-import.js**

```
const contentful = require('contentful-management');

const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken:'AUTHTOKEN'
});

client
  .getSpace('SPACE')
  .then(space => {
    space.createAsset({
      fields: {
        title: {
          'en-US': 'Example 1'
        },
        description: {
          'en-US': 'Example Description'
        },
        file: {
          'en-US': {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            fileName: 'example1.jpeg',
            upload:'https://example1.jpeg'
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    space.createAsset({
      fields: {
        title: {
          'en-US': 'Example 2'
        },
        description: {
          'en-US': 'Example Description'
        },
        file: {
          'en-US': {
            contentType: 'image/jpeg',
            fileName: 'example2.jpeg',
            upload:'https://example2.jpeg'
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    //... 700 other assets
  })
  .then(asset => asset.processForAllLocales())
  .then(asset => console.log(asset))
  .catch(console.error)
```

And the `CLI` function I run is

```
contentful space migration ./contentful/contentful-import.js
```

Which is returning the error of `TypeError: migrationCreator is not a function`

I have looked elsewhere in the Contentful documentation but I cannot see anything that helps.

Am I attempting to upload assets correctly or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script you have written is a "normal" node.js script.

```
node contentful-import.js
```

Will do the job just fine for that. `contentful space migration` uses specific scripts in a particular format (they have to export a `migrationCreator`). A valid migration would be:

```
module.exports = function (migration, context) {
  const dog = migration.createContentType('dog');
  const name = dog.createField('name');
  name.type('Symbol').required(true);
};
```

The contentful-cli uses [contentful-migration](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-migration) under the hood. You'll find more documentation there.

I'll open a PR for the CLI documentation right away. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. With this in mind, am I best to store `JSON` values for the multiple assets I want to upload in a seperate file, then `map` the `createFields` as  `entries` to a new `content-type`?

Comment: If you want to transform entries you can have a look at [derivelinkedentriesconfig](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-migration#derivelinkedentriesconfig). For further questions about migration tooling the github repository is probably the place to go. :)